# Arch Linux: Error in makepkg w/ creating another user

Tags: linux, shell, archlinux

Like the title suggests, I'm using Arch Linuxx on a virtualbox with just xfce4 installed
I want to create a script that installs yay. I know that the makepkg command cannot be run on root so I decided to create a script.

```
# Setting up AUR and installing yay in this machine
cd /home
mkdir data
cd /home/data
sudo useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 liveuser) liveuser
su liveuser
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
chmod 777 yay
cd yay./
makepkg -si
exit
userdel -r liveuser
```

But the result I get is this:

```
[root@archevaris Desktop]# ./APPINSTALLER.sh
[liveuser@archevaris EVARIS]$
```

It does not execute the rest of the code properly. I don't see any changes in the /home/data folder. Is there anything wrong with the script I made??
The script above is based on the forum I made: [https://linux.org/threads/yay-not-installing-in-arch-linux.27414/#post-84056][1]

Any issues with the script?

Comment: `cd yay./` should be `cd ./yay/`. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Nope it doesn't. Nothing changes.

Comment: Do you know on which command does it stop? Try putting `echo doing X` after each command to see where it stops

Comment: I did like you said and got this:                                                                         doing cd /home
doing mkdir EVARIS
doing cd /home/EVARIS
doing sudo useradd -p $1$ncDM79Lu$DeD2u5sunACy26fgX36ti1 liveuser
So, what do I do next? Looks like it does till creating the user "liveuser" and switching to it..

Comment: I think the problem is that after switching to another user the process waits until the subshell finishes and after `exit` the script will continue. You have to change the way you run commands as another user. Have a read here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/

Comment: I used the runuser command like you showed in your page but I get this: ==> ERROR: Failed to create the directory $BUILDDIR (/home/liveuser/Desktop).
    Aborting...
And before that command, I get a Permission Denied message to /home/liveuser/Desktop [https://pastebin.com/FpkG1DMU (My Shell code now) ] What to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voilà. I commented it accurately so you can see.

```
#!/bin/bash
##################################################################################################################
# This section here is just to understand where the script is and then come back here at the end of the execution.
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
# Following cycle to resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do 
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
# If $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" 
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
##################################################################################################################
# Want to go back to the symlink if that is supposed behaviour? Then delete until here and uncomment next line
#DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
##################################################################################################################
#
# HERE IS WHERE YOUR ACTUAL SCRIPT BEGINS:
#
# Defining variables:
TEMPACCOUNT="liveuser"
DESTINATION="/home/$TEMPACCOUNT"
# Adding your temp user and giving it a home folder where it can downloads the source code
useradd -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 $TEMPACCOUNT) $TEMPACCOUNT
# He has to launch the command as non-root user, but he'll need to give admin permission at the end. Adding to sudoers.
echo "$TEMPACCOUNT ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
# Next line is to install packages needed to install yay. I may have forgotten some. I leave the line commented.
#pacman -S git make fakeroot go binutils --noconfirm
# Move to his home folder
cd $DESTINATION
# Create the script in his home folder
echo '#!/bin/bash' > $DESTINATION/yay-setup.sh
echo -e "git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay-bin.git\ncd $DESTINATION/yay-bin\nmakepkg --noconfirm -si" >> $DESTINATION/yay-setup.sh
chmod +x $DESTINATION/yay-setup.sh
# Done, now pass the following commands to the SU session we're about to open. << is crucial here, That's what you missed
su $TEMPACCOUNT<<'EOF'
set -e
/bin/bash "yay-setup.sh"
exit
EOF
# Remove the temp user from sudoers file by deleting last line
sed '$d' /etc/sudoers > /etc/sudoers
# The following line is actually pretty useless, userdel -r will wipe this anyway
rm -R yay-*
# And we go back to home sweet home
cd $DIR
# And we delete the temp user
userdel -r $TEMPACCOUNT
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH! Thank you so much! I clearly understand everything right now! It does work on my VM for now. Thanks A LOT!